# How do i query model managers in my function based views for single_page(detail.html)

Tags: python, django

I'm finding it difficult to query a custom django model manager in my function based detail view. How can i resolve this?

I'm using django 2.2.

in my models.py file, i have this code below, which works perfectly. Querying for the listview is working fine and when i query the detail view using get_object_or_404(Modelname, id), the detail views works too but when i try to query it using my custom model manager, i keep getting this error 
"movie_detail() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'".

i've also tried removing--->

```
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('core:movie_detail', args=[self.id,])
```

from my movie model when querying the model manager, but am still get same error

How can i resolve this?

## my models.py

```
class MovieManager(models.Manager):

    def all_with_related_persons(self):
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        qs = qs.select_related('director')
        qs = qs.prefetch_related('writers', 'actors')
        return qs

class Movie(models.Model):
    NOT_RATED   =   0
    RATED_G     =   1
    RATED_PG    =   2
    RATED_R     =   3
    RATINGS     =   (
                    (NOT_RATED, 'NR - Not Rated'),
                    (RATED_G, 'G - General Audiences'),
                    (RATED_PG, ' PG - Parental Guidance' 'Suggested'),
                    (RATED_R, 'R - Restricted'),
                )
    title       =     models.CharField(max_length=140)
    plot        =     models.TextField()
    year        =     models.PositiveIntegerField()
    rating      =     models.IntegerField(choices=RATINGS, default=NOT_RATED)
    runtime     =     models.PositiveIntegerField()
    website     =     models.URLField(blank=True)
    director    =     models.ForeignKey(to='Person',
                                    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                    related_name="directed",
                                    null=True,
                                    blank=True)
    writer      =     models.ManyToManyField(to="Person", related_name="writing_credits", blank=True)
    actors      =     models.ManyToManyField(to="Person", through="Role", related_name="acting_credits", blank=True)
    objects     =     MovieManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} ({})'.format(self.title, self.year)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('core:movie_detail', args=[self.id,])

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-year', 'title',)
```

<--- Views.py --->

## My List view

```
def movie_list(request):
    object_list =   Movie.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(object_list, 12)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    try:
        page = paginator.page(page_number)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
    # If page is not an integer deliver the first page
        page = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
    # If page is out of range deliver last page of results
        page = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    context     =   {
                    'object_list': object_list,
                    'products': page,
                    'page': page,
                }
    template    =   'core/movie_list.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

## DetailView without custom model manager.(This works)

```
def movie_detail(request, id):
    object_list = get_object_or_404(Person, id=id)
    context     =   {'movie': object_list}
    template    =   'core/person_detail.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

## DetailView with custom model manager.(This doesn't work. throws an error "movie_detail() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'")

```
def movie_detail(request):
    object_list =   Movie.objects.all_with_related_persons()
    context     =   {'movie': object_list}
    template    =   'core/movie_detail.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

## My url path to the detail_view

```
path('<id>/', views.movie_detail, name="movie_detail"),
```

I expect detail view to return queries based on what i queried in my custom model manager.

Comment: dirkgroten, thanks.  adding id to the detail view solved it.

Answer (score -1):

Your url pattern for the `movie_detail` view is passing an `id` kwarg to your view, so your view needs to accept this `id` as argument. Instead of

```
def movie_detail(request)
```

you should define

```
def movie_detail(request, id)
```

The error you see just says: `movie_detail` was called with keyword argument `id`, meaning it was called like this: `movie_detail(request=the_request, id=some_id)` which can't work if it's defined to only have one argument, `request`.

But also, since you're making a detail view for one object, you should probably do something with the `id` to select the specific object:

```
def movie_detail(request, id):
    object_list = Movie.objects.all_with_related_persons()
    try:
        movie = object_list.get(id=id)
    except Movie.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    context     =   {'movie': movie}
    template    =   'core/movie_detail.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: can't use 'objects' with a custom model manager. will throw error

Comment: of course you can redefine `objects` to be your custom manager.

Comment: implementation of the manager seems wrong now that I think more about it

Comment: it's perfectly valid

Comment: wait, if the user overrides the default model manager then what is the need of using it with objects. shouldn't that just be Movie.objects.all() ?

Comment: `objects` *is* the model manager. The OP doesn't want to override the default QuerySet otherwise he would have overridden `get_queryset(self)`. That would change the default behaviour also for `Movie.objects.all()`. He just wanted to add a new method, `all_with_related_persons()`.